# JAXB eagerly fetches fields marked FetchType.LAZY even when EntityManager has been cleared(), closed() and set to null

Tags: jpa, jaxb, lazy-loading, eclipselink, moxy

I bow to the apt stackoverflow community and humbly seek guidance (I bow my head in subservience as I write this)

I have the following Entity class/bean which has a mixture of JPA/EclipseLink/JAXB/Moxy annotations:  (btw EventBase is just a @MappedSuperclass that holds additional fields)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EVENTS")
@XmlRootElement
public class Event extends EventBase {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    private long eventCID;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "APPLICATIONCID")
    private CustomerApplication customerApplication;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTOMERCID")
    private Customer customer;

    ....
}
```

Here's my code to marshal this entity (outer class excluded for brevity)

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Event event = myInstance.populateEvent();
    myInstance.buildXMLFromEvent(event);
}

public Event populateEvent() {

    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(this.persistenceUnit);
    EntityManager em = null;

    Event event = null;
    try {
        em = emf.createEntityManager();
        event = (Event) em.createQuery("Select object(e) from Event e where e.eventCID = 55000").getSingleResult();
        em.clear();
        em.detach(event);
        em.close();
        em = null;
        emf.close();
        emf = null;
    } catch (Exception e) { // just test code so catching general exception
        log.error("Unexpected error: " + e);
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.clear();
            em.close();
        }
    }
    return event;
}

private void buildXMLFromEvent(Event event) {

    System.out.println("Marshalling now:");
    JAXBContext jc;
    try {
        jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Event.class);
        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.valueOf(true));
        JAXBElement<Event> jaxbElement = new JAXBElement<Event>(new QName("event"), Event.class, event);
        marshaller.marshal(jaxbElement, System.out);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
    }
}
```

The generated xml actually goes and eagerly fetches all of the member objects of my Event entity bean!  i.e) Customer, CustomerApplication and any other mappings which I've excluded for brevity.  I'm using EclipseLink as my JPA provider and Moxy for JAXB.    What am I doing wrong here?  You can see that not only are the entityManager AND entityManagerFactory instances cleared, closed and set to null, but I've also gone ahead and detached the root Event entity.  Moreover, the fetchtype has explicitly been set to LAZY!

How is it that JAXB can eagerly fetch when the Event object has been detached?  I thought closing the entityManager in itself detaches all managed objects?   Is there some cached session context that JAXB is hanging on to?   If so, why is it not even honoring the explicitly defined fetch strategy?
Many thanks in advance!

Ustad

Comment: Ok, it seems adding the @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) annotation at the class level has now prevented those member objects from being fetched.   I'm still stumped as to how objects can still be fetched with a closed/cleared/null entityManager.. unless I'm missing something - which I probably am!

Comment: It`s not very good practice to expose your entities directly, to improve your design , you could consider creating DTO objects for that, and control the view by yourself

Comment: Hi Alexey, thanks for the comments.. the example doesn't necessarily mirror my design, I created this for the purposes of illustration...

Comment: Which ORM implementation you are using?

Comment: @Alexey: I'm using EclipseLink as my JPA provider and Moxy for JAXB

Comment: I have submitted the answer for you, was that helpful?

Comment: @ustad  I have the same issue, I added @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) annotation at the class level but it did not solve it, could you please show how you did it ?

Comment: @SamyOmar sorry, that was code from my last job so I don't have the source.. You can try googling "Blaise Doughan" he's the team lead for the TopLink/EclipseLink JAXB & SDO, see if you can contact him.. best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

If eclipselink is in standalone mode, then only ManyToMany and OneToMany relations is actually uses lazy-loading, for others fetch attribute is ignored and equal to EAGER.

Here is documentation for that http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Mapping/Basic_Mappings/Lazy_Basics

> One-to-one: By default, EclipseLink JPA ignores the fetch attribute and
>   default javax.persistence.FetchType.EAGER applies.
>
> Many-to-one: EclipseLink JPA performs lazy loading when the fetch
>   attribute is set to javax.persistence.FetchType.LAZY.
>
> Basic: By default, EclipseLink JPA ignores the fetch attribute and
>   default javax.persistence.FetchType.EAGER applies.

That`s why your entities are loaded with relations.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your research and help!  That reference doc is very useful!   The fetch strategy was always EAGER despite what relationship I had.   Please see my first comment after posting the question.. I'll paste here again:

_"Ok, it seems adding the @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD) annotation at the class level has now prevented those member objects from being fetched. I'm still stumped as to how objects can still be fetched with a closed/cleared/null entityManager.. unless I'm missing something - which I probably am!"_

I still don't know the answer to that.. tnx!

Comment: With eager fetch type, all relations will be fetched when you call event = (Event) em.createQuery("Select object(e) from Event e where e.eventCID = 55000").getSingleResult();. I think that`s why you have all relations in your XML, but I do not understand how field access for jaxb could fix it. The only thought is that you have no getters for that fields.